# Why html elements still have offsets in my code?

Tags: html, css

I set `margin` and `padding` of my `div` and `body` elements to `0` but I see some offset between my `div`s exist still. Also I use inline blocks.

This is my example:

```css
.background{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.page{
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.title-boss-offset{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width:70%;
}

.title-boss {
    width: 29%;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.title-boss-offset, .title-boss{
    border-width:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 15em;
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
<div class="page">
    <div class="title-boss-offset"></div>
    <div class="title-boss"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: you have spaces between your elements

Comment: `<div class="title-boss-offset"></div><div class="title-boss"></div>`--->no offset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be sure to remove the spaces between the elements when you use `display: inline-block`. Or see the pure CSS solution.

### Stripping spaces

But this will not (note that I added a `line-height:0` to the parent to get rid of the bottom margin) :

```css
.background{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.page{
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:0;
}

.title-boss-offset{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width:70%;
}

.title-boss {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.title-boss-offset, .title-boss{
    border-width:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 15em;
    word-spacing: normal
    
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="title-boss-offset"></div><!--
    --><div class="title-boss"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Pure CSS:

You cantake advantage of the table display that strip spaces between cells, by setting the parent style to `display: table;`
important parts are :

```
.parent{
  display: table; 
  width: 100%; 
  table-layout: fixed; 
  line-height: 0;
  word-spacing: -2em; /*cross-browser quirks*/
}
.children{
  display: inline-block; 
  word-spacing: normal; /*cross-browser quirks*/
}
```

```css
.background{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.page{
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    width:80%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-spacing: -2em;
    line-height:0;
}

.title-boss-offset{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    width:70%;
}

.title-boss {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.title-boss-offset, .title-boss{
    border-width:0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 15em;
    word-spacing: normal
    
}
```

```html
<body class="background">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="title-boss-offset"></div>
    <div class="title-boss"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use the `inline-block` property, browsers automatically add some space between it. Read [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more info about it.

You could easily fix it, for example by adding a float:

```
.title-boss-offset, .title-boss {
  /* other props */
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the white-space and line break in your HTML markup which causes this issue. There are two options to resolve the "problem":

- remove the line breaks and white-space from your code
- set the font-size of the parent element to '0'

try using code as single line. It wont show event you set width 70%,30% of yours elements
Or use **float** property

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the *linebreaks* between the ìnline-block` elements, which causes those spaces.

One way to prevent those is the move the *closing* tag of such an element down into the next line and put the next *opening* tag directly after it in the same line, like this in your example:

```
<body class="background">
  <div class="page">
    <div class="title-boss-offset">
    </div><div class="title-boss">
  </div></div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7voowbf7/1/